# Error installing joomla on wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have installed Wamp Server with Apache 2.4.9- Mysql-5.6.17-php 5.5.12- 64bit.
I have installed all well, the icon is green and I did this from a video from youtube. Port 80 on skype is turned off. When I check port 80 it say that Apache is using this port. After making the new folder in folder www and extracted joomla to this folder all should be ok. But when I go to lokalhost, your projects and open. I do not see the installation page from joomla. It The browser is white.How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

- Left click on the WAMP icon in task bar
- Then move mouse over PHP >
- Then go down and click on php.ini
- Search: error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"  (**your path can be different**)

Make sure where is your `error.log` file. Open the file and copy the errors (if any) Please, let us now the error.

**NOTE:** If in front of `error_log` you see a `;` please, remove it and restart apache